# Multiple ACTION_DOWN events do the same

Tags: android, button, multi-touch

I want to make 3 buttons touchable at once so you can touch a button without removing the finger from another one. I did it so far with ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_POINTER_1_DOWN and ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN in this order:

```
      public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {


            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button1:
                {   playSound(SOUND1,  1.0f) ;};
                    break;
                case R.id.button2:
                {   playSound(SOUND2,  1.0f) ;};
                    break;
                case R.id.button3:
                {   playSound(SOUND3,  1.0f) ;};
                    break;}

            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_1_DOWN) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button1:
                {   playSound(SOUND1,  1.0f) ;};
                    break;
                case R.id.button2:
                {   playSound(SOUND2,  1.0f) ;};
                    break;
                case R.id.button3:
                {   playSound(SOUND3,  1.0f) ;};

                    break;}

            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button1:
                {   playSound(SOUND1,  1.0f) ;};

                    break;
                case R.id.button2:
                {   playSound(SOUND2,  1.0f) ;};

                    break;
                case R.id.button3:
                {   playSound(SOUND3,  1.0f) ;};
                    break;}
```

There's no error or warning if I compile and run this project on my phone.

But when I make a second touch, the same sound as on the first one plays.
Example: Finger 2 presses button 2 (sound2 playing). While holding finger 2 on button 2, I touch button 3 with my finger 3. I expected, that sound3 is playing, but sound 2 plays again.

I already tried with "return true" but that didn't change anything.

A few people have this problem as well but no one really find a solution in these threads.

Alex

Update: I just found out that it doesn't matter where i click. Even if I click on a blank space, the button, where the other finger is on, reacts again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that the code you are using is deprecated.  I believe the following code (snatched from the Android Training Document, link to follow) should help solve your problem.

http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html

```
private int mActivePointerId;

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
{
    ....
    // Get the pointer ID
    mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(0);

    // ... Many touch events later...

    // Use the pointer ID to find the index of the active pointer 
    // and fetch its position
    int pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
    // Get the pointer's current position
    float x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
    float y = event.getY(pointerIndex);
}
```

You can then use the x, y coordinates to determine which button they are pressing, and activate your sound.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know about that. Might you tell me, how I can make the app ignore the onTouch, so the OnTouchEvent gets called? It would be awesome

Comment: You would have to make a custom class extend View and override onTouchEvent... see the source code at http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView.onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29

Comment: Thanks a lot sir I now divided the display width into parts where the buttons would be. I were always scared from that X/Y stuff since i just hate maths, but now I'm good with it. Thanks again